# $\surd (I^e)=(\surd I)^e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

I'm having troubles to prove the $\surd (I^e)=(\surd I)^e$ in the part (ii). I'm trying a lot proving the inclusions $\subset$ and $\supset$ without any success, I really need help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: About the notation: $I^e$ is the image of $I$ under $f$, i.e. $I^e := f(I)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer in this case, yes, because $f$ is surjective, but $I^e$ is exactly the ideal generated by $f(I)$

Comment: Let $s \in \sqrt{I^e}$. Now consider $r$ with $f(r) = s$. And the powers of $s$ and $r$. That leads to $\subset$. For the other inclusion, let $r \in \sqrt{I}$ and $s = f(r)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thank you very much, I was stuck there. Make an answer so that I will be able to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r \in \sqrt{I}$. That means $r^n \in I$ for some $n > 0$. But then

$$f(r)^n = f(r^n) \in f(I) = I^e,$$

so $f(r) \in \sqrt{I^e}$, thus $f(\sqrt{I}) = (\sqrt{I})^e \subset \sqrt{I^e}$.

Conversely, let $s \in \sqrt{I^e}$ and $r \in f^{-1}(\{s\})$ (since $f$ is surjective, such an $r$ exists). Let $n > 0$ such that $s^n \in I^e$. Then $f(r^n) = f(r)^n = s^n \in I^e$, so $r^n \in f^{-1}(I^e) = I$, hence $r \in \sqrt{I}$ and $s \in f(\sqrt{I}) = (\sqrt{I})^e$, hence $\sqrt{I^e} \subset (\sqrt{I})^e$.

Comment: Thank you very much again.